# Javascript NodeList.forEach() not updating all found items

Tags: javascript, foreach, nodelist

I don't understand why this function only seems to update the last item in the nodelist. I want the function to add the indicator element to all li elements that have a child ul element. The function finds all the elements, but only the last one seems to get updated.

```
var ulElementsWithChildren = document.querySelectorAll('ul.test>li ul');

var indicator = document.createElement('span');
indicator.innerHTML = '+';

ulElementsWithChildren.forEach(function(item) {
  item.parentElement.appendChild(indicator);

});
```

html

```
  <ul class="test">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Child Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4
    <ul>
      <li>Child Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 5
    <ul>
      <li>Child Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DLYCK/cgk2t74t/)

Comment: `indicator.cloneNode(true)` will work too. It lets you take an existing node structure and duplicate it entirely.

Comment: good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your indicator declaration inside of your foreach and it will work.

example:

```
ulElementsWithChildren.forEach(function(item) {
    var indicator = document.createElement('span');
    indicator.innerHTML = '+';
    item.parentElement.appendChild(indicator);
});
```

You're only creating a single span element.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You create one `<span>`.

You then append it in lots of different places.

Since an element can only appear in one place, you move it each time until you get to the end of the loop.

You need to create a new span each time you go around the loop.